# jQuery - ui.keyCode.TAB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am doing a check on a keypress event (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB), and I am consistently getting -

```
$.ui.keyCode.TAB is null or not an object.
```

What could be causing that? am I missing a .js file somewhere?

Comment: Use `$.ui.keyCode.TAB` (note the period after `$`)

Comment: Shawn is right. I copied it incorrectly, but the period is there in my non-working code.

Comment: Did you include everything? http://jsfiddle.net/kWEhu/

Comment: What do you see when you `alert($.ui.version)`?

Answer (score 6):

If you do not need jquery UI, you could use the following enum instead:

```
if (event.keyCode == KeyCodes.Tab) {
    // some code here
}

KeyCodes = {
    BackSpace           : 8  ,
    Tab                 : 9  ,
    Enter               : 13 ,
    Shift               : 16 ,
    Ctrl                : 17 ,
    Alt                 : 18 ,
    PauseBreak          : 19 ,
    CapsLock            : 20 ,
    Esc                 : 27 ,
    PageUp              : 33 ,
    PageDown            : 34 ,
    End                 : 35 ,
    Home                : 36 ,
    ArrowLeft           : 37 ,
    ArrowUp             : 38 ,
    ArrowRight          : 39 ,
    ArrowDown           : 40 ,
    Insert              : 45 ,
    Delete              : 46 ,
    Digit0              : 48 ,
    Digit1              : 49 ,
    Digit2              : 50 ,
    Digit3              : 51 ,
    Digit4              : 52 ,
    Digit5              : 53 ,
    Digit6              : 54 ,
    Digit7              : 55 ,
    Digit8              : 56 ,
    Digit9              : 57 ,
    A                   : 65 ,
    B                   : 66 ,
    C                   : 67 ,
    D                   : 68 ,
    E                   : 69 ,
    F                   : 70 ,
    G                   : 71 ,
    H                   : 72 ,
    I                   : 73 ,
    J                   : 74 ,
    K                   : 75 ,
    L                   : 76 ,
    M                   : 77 ,
    N                   : 78 ,
    O                   : 79 ,
    P                   : 80 ,
    Q                   : 81 ,
    R                   : 82 ,
    S                   : 83 ,
    T                   : 84 ,
    U                   : 85 ,
    V                   : 86 ,
    W                   : 87 ,
    X                   : 88 ,
    Y                   : 89 ,
    Z                   : 90 ,
    WindowLeft          : 91 ,
    WindowRight         : 92 ,
    SelectKey           : 93 ,
    Numpad0             : 96 ,
    Numpad1             : 97 ,
    Numpad2             : 98 ,
    Numpad3             : 99 ,
    Numpad4             : 100,
    Numpad5             : 101,
    Numpad6             : 102,
    Numpad7             : 103, 
    Numpad8             : 104,
    Numpad9             : 105,
    Multiply            : 106,
    Add                 : 107,
    Subtract            : 109,
    DecimalPoint        : 110,
    Divide              : 111,
    F1                  : 112,
    F2                  : 113,
    F3                  : 114,
    F4                  : 115,
    F5                  : 116,
    F6                  : 117,
    F7                  : 118,
    F8                  : 119,
    F9                  : 120,
    F10                 : 121,
    F11                 : 122,
    F12                 : 123,
    NumLock             : 144,
    ScrollLock          : 145,
    SemiColon           : 186,
    Equal               : 187,
    Comma               : 188,
    Dash                : 189,
    Period              : 190,
    ForwardSlash        : 191,
    GraveAccent         : 192,
    BracketOpen         : 219,
    BackSlash           : 220,
    BracketClose        : 221,
    SingleQuote         : 222 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.ui.keyCode.TAB` comes with jquery UI. Make sure you've include the `.js` for jQuery and jQuery UI.

If that still fails, try `jQuery.ui.keyCode.TAB` or simply `9`.

Comment: I have both of those js files included. (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js)

Comment: @Michael If you look at `jquery-ui.js` the definition for `$.ui.keyCode.*` comes close to the beginning. It definitely exists unless you didn't include it right (jquery should be included before jquery-ui). Might help if you can share the offending code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `$ui.keyCode.TAB` in your code, so just do:

```
if(event.keyCode === 9) { //TAB

}
```

Comment: That's the thing. I'd love to be able to do that, but in the root code for autocomplete, there is a comparison to $ui.keyCode.TAB, so i can't change it.

Comment: @MichaelWarren why can't you change it? that is your code. you can do whatever u want! lol

Comment: The error comes from jquery-ui.js, which references ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js. Non-changeable.

Comment: Very changeable. and u can just use `9`. You code is the one with the handler.

Comment: How am I able to change the js file located here - ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js. ?

Comment: @MichaelWarren change your file that uses jquery-ui, not jquery-ui itself.